# Momentary use of mixed AH batteries in series?

Tags: batteries

Obviously a circuit using mixed batteries in series is a bad idea. My question is for momentary use is it that bad? I have a starter on a dirt bike that I would like to push 24V through (it's capable). The main battery instead of going to the starter relay would go to another battery first and then the starter relay. The secondary battery is not part of the charging circuit.

Comment: voltage is not pushed through a device ... voltage is applied across a device ... the voltage pushes current through the device

Comment: It's a common fix for a series of motorcycles produced by several manufacturers that by speeding up the starter motor with More voltage the motorcycle will start faster and more reliably.